# BASH SCRIPT, environment variables and PID

Tags: bash, pid

I need a little help with bash sctipt. I need BASH script, using environment variables:

First script will create an array of variables, which are stored in the script and the PID and -f. Assigned to an array of variables in the environment variables.
This script will be displayed his PID and runs the second script.
The second script will be displayed the first script PID and the list by using -f (from first part) option in the environment variable and terminate the operation of the first script...

Comment: What do you have so far? Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: What is the end purpose of the script, what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: because i am green on that, i need that program as soos as i can get. and if someone can help me i appreciate that...

Answer (score 0):

I am hesitant to go much further since this is a hw problem and i am unsure what you are trying to do, so this is what i can do....

in bash $$ will give you your current pid for the script

as for arrays, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html